# Parsing sub-element of enclosure tag from XML with bash script

Tags: bash, parsing, grep

I am trying to extract a URL to a file from an `<enclosure>` tag in an XML file. The issue is that the order of the sub-elements in the `<enclosure>` tags seems to change. Normally it looks like this:

```
<enclosure length="3026587648" url="2015-0805.mpeg" type="video/mpeg" />
```

But sometimes the URL comes first, which means using `cut -f` is not reliable.

I have come as far as to get the entire enclosure tag with `grep -m 1 "enclosure"`, and the URL with `cut -d " " -f 3`.

But there must be a better way to extract the URL, regardless of where it appears?

I'm currently on a Slackware installation and xmllint and xmlstarlet doesn't seem to be available.

Thanks for any feedback!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
grep -m 1 "enclosure" yourfile.txt | sed -n 's/^.*\(url="[^"]*"\).*$/\1/p'
```